# Error in newff example of Neurolab

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I just installed Neurolab and I tried one the provided examples (Feed Forward Multilayer Perceptron (newff)):

```
import neurolab as nl
import numpy as np

# Create train samples
x = np.linspace(-7, 7, 20)
y = np.sin(x) * 0.5

size = len(x)

inp = x.reshape(size,1)
tar = y.reshape(size,1)

# Create network with 2 layers and random initialized
net = nl.net.newff([[-7, 7]],[5, 1])

# Train network
error = net.train(inp, tar, epochs=500, show=100, goal=0.02)

# Simulate network
out = net.sim(inp)
```

But I encounter this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/newff.py", line 17, in <module>
    error = net.train(inp, tar, epochs=500, show=100, goal=0.02)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neurolab\core.py", line 165, in train
    return self.trainf(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neurolab\core.py", line 349, in __call__
    train(net, *args)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\neurolab\train\spo.py", line 73, in __call__
    from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs
ImportError: No module named scipy.optimize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed training routine call, which is probably setting `.ci` attribute in the network object. Thus the error is not in the example but in your modification.

#### update (OP changed quetsion)

Now the problem is extremely simple - you do not have `scipy` installed.

Comment: I did nothing, I just installed it!

Comment: Sorry, I posted a different error :/ I just edited the right error.

Comment: do you have scipy installed? it does not seem so